# Difference between keytool and openssl?

Tags: java, openssl, keytool

We can generate certificate through keytool like this

```
keytool -genkey -alias initcert  -keyalg  RSA  -keystore keycloak.jks  -validity 365  -keysize 2048
```

and through openssl also like this

```
Openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"
```

What is the difference between these two technique and which we should use?

Comment: The difference is that they produce different file formats. If you're intending Java to use the files you may as well use the keytool.

Comment: @EJP So no any major difference than formats? and certificates generated through OpenSSL wont import from keytool?

Comment: These OpenSSL commands use separate files in PEM format, which keytool (and other java programs) cannot read or write directly. OpenSSL can convert to and from single-file PKCS12, which keytool can use and so can many java programs; in j9 PKCS12 becomes the default so more java programs can use it. There are dozens at least of Q&As on stack about this, many on SO even though it should be offtopic. FYI `keytool -genkeypair` can do subject&issuer name on the command line like `-dname CN=blah,O=bleh` and since j7 can do extensions on command line while openssl uses a file for extensions.

Comment: Note there is a big difference between cert _with privatekey_ (for your own identity) as you have here, and a cert by itself (for someone else usually a CA). `keytool` _can_ directly read or write a cert by itself in either DER or PEM format; a bit confusingly it calls the latter `-rfc`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 So the certificates created with OpenSSL cannt be import in client machine by `keytool -import` command? If no how to import openssl certificates?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I found the question useful