# Enabling-ssl-https for the keycloak-server

Tags: ssl, keycloak

I am using keycloak-8.0.1 in standalone configuration . I am trying to enable SSL/Https for Keycloak server running on my Test machine (A.B.C.D) , token request will be requested from machine (X.Y.Z.P).

(Will there be any CORS/CSRF issue for the generated token , looks like yes ? And will Keycloak over SSL help to solve this?) Nevertheless i require SSL enabling .

So went ahead with https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#enabling-ssl-https-for-the-keycloak-server

Step 1 Run command :

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keystore keycloak.jks -validity 10950
```

...
two files `server.key` and `keycloak.jks` got created.
Question : should i used `localhost` here or better to use IP `A.B.C.D` of my Test machine? Though documentation says `localhost` so went ahead with that.

Step 2 Generate a certificate request :

```
$ keytool -certreq -alias yourdomain -keystore keycloak.jks > keycloak.careq
```

I can also generate the cert request using `localhost`/`A.B.C.D`.

Step 3: Send the cert req created in above step to CA and download the root cert from CA(`root.crt`) and import using command:

```
keytool -import -keystore keycloak.jks -file root.crt -alias root
```

Do i have to skip this step for `localhost` and if not how to generate root.crt for `localhost`.

step 4: last step is to import CA generated certificate to keystore

```
$ keytool -import -alias yourdomain -keystore keycloak.jks -file your-certificate.cer
```

Question: Now i have only two files generated in very first step "server.key" and `keycloak.jks`
and from where i should get `root.crt` and `your-certificate.cer` ? I tried uploading the ca request to CAcert.org but they dont create certificate for localhost DNS.

I already went through lot of links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994878/using-key-tool-to-make-a-csr-how-do-i-make-a-cert-for-tomcat-ssl) , [link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347116/how-to-create-keystore-and-truststore-using-self-signed-certificate) , [link3](https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309) [link4](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/06/13/how-to-keystore-creating-jks-file-from-existing-private-key-and-certificate/) and getting confused
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1- 
If you are testing this in your local machine you can use `localhost` but better would be if you are using `IP-address` or `host name`

Answer 3
Again if its for your testing you can use Self Sign Certificate only,No need to go to Ads Certificate authority.

Answer 4-
So for localhost or your machine IP simple Create Certificate with the help of `keytool`

```
keytool -genkey -alias initcert -ext san=ip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -keyalg  RSA -keystore keycloak.jks-validity 365  -keysize 2048
```

Export the certificates

```
keytool -export -noprompt -trustcacerts -keystore keycloak.jks -alias initcert -file keycloak.cer -storepass changeit
```

Import Certificates into Client machine Java Keystore

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "initcert" -file keycloak.cer -keystore /workspace/tools/jdk/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , Looks like it is away from Keycloak documentation . Can you please tell me how I can use java keystore to run Keycloak application or any other application which needs SSL certificates.

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472764/difference-between-keytool-and-openssl